# Transform OpenCV image data type to Devil image format and vice-versa

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cuda, devil

I want to use a CUDA-enabled SIFT library but I am using the OpenCV driver to get images from the webcam? The Cuda library is using the Devil Library for image data types.
Should I transform the images from OpenCV data types to Devil? Or Should I use another method for getting images from the webcam[devil compatible data types]?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the DeviL but from the manual it states that it supports the following formats:

```
IL_COLOUR_INDEX
IL_RGB
IL_RGBA
IL_BGR
IL_BGRA
IL_LUMINANCE
```

of varying bit depths.

When loading images, OpenCV also supports most of these image types and bit depths and conversion between them is pretty straightforward (see the `convertTo()` function in the openCV documentation) .  Using a webcam may be more complex.

It is difficult to answer your question directly without knowing the interface of the specific library.   If the library accepts a devil image in a specific form, then it is likely you will have to give it in that form.  OpenCV will likely be able to output data in the required form; if not, you may have to write code to transform it yourself.